# Is the `else:` correct/necessary in this Python program?

Tags: python, if-statement

Is the line of `else:` correct/necessary in this Python program?

```
from random import randrange
for n in range(10):
    r = randrange(0,10) # get random int in [0,10)
    if n==r: continue # skip iteration if n=r
    if n>r: break # exit the loop if n>r
    print n
else:
    print "wow, you are lucky!\n"
if n<9:
    print "better luck next time\n
```

Comment: Well, the program won't even compile, but only because of the `if n = r:` part.

Comment: @Rik Poggi: This question is asking about the syntactic validity of an `else:` construct in a certain context, rather than a code review of the entire snippet of code, so it fits here, not there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

> Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement

So yes, it's correct in your example. Although I've never been a fan of it, using an else clause on a loop makes code confusing at first, I'd rather use a boolean flag for achieving the same effect. IMHO `else` should be used only for conditionals.

Answer (score 3):

```
from random import randrange
for n in range(10):
    r = randrange(0,10)
    if n=r: continue    # there should be ==
    if n>r: break
    print n             # should be "\n" ?
else:
    print "wow, you are lucky!\n" # Yes, you are! Your python interpreter can make miracles :). Try to run me.append(SexyChick(10)) and let's see what happens!
```

`for...else` construct is actually valid. `else` branch is executed if the loop has not been terminated by `break`. Look [here](http://psung.blogspot.com/2007/12/for-else-in-python.html).